# Undeployment from jenkins to weblogic servers

Tags: jenkins, weblogic

I try to undeploy from jenkins to weblogic servers and my scripts is java -cp D:\Jenkins\additional\wlfullclient.jar weblogic.Deployer -debug -remote -verbose -undeploy -name MTS -appversion 4.5.9.0.5 -targets MTS-APP-01,MTS-JOB-01,MTSWS-APP-01,MTSWS-APP-02  -adminurl t3://100.115.35.14:7001 -user *** -password ***

the app name and version is true but I got the following errors:
weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149001]No application named "MTS [Version=4.5.9.0.5]" exists for operation "undeploy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your application doesn't use weblogic application versioning. I would try without "-appversion 4.5.9.0.5" after confirming that the application name is "MTS"